# Google Cloud Dataflow SQL Join Issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have one Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic where I receive messages from source system, and I have one table stored in BigQuery that I use to enrich the Pub/Sub topic messages, lets say, Table_A and store the enriched messages in another BigQuery table. The problem is that when some data in BigQuery Table_A changes this is not reflecting in the final results. What is the problem here? I am using the GCP Dataflow SQL to write this job.

I already tried creating the query in a different ways and also enabling the Streaming Engine.